# Is there a way to ask online booksellers to pull pirated editions of my books?

Tags: publishing, legal, copyright

Eight of my books are available on Google Books as 100% online, downloadable, but no Creative Commons licensing. Now I am starting to see them show up in bookstores, in versions I didn't have printed. Amazon has a listing beginning with a statement that is both boilerplate and false:

> This is a reproduction of a book published before 1923. This book may have occasional imperfections such as missing or blurred pages, poor pictures, errant marks, etc. that were either part of the original artifact, or were introduced by the scanning process. We believe this work is culturally important, and despite the imperfections, have elected to bring it back into print as part of our continuing commitment to the preservation of printed works worldwide. We appreciate your understanding of the imperfections in the preservation process, and hope you enjoy this valuable book.

And then it cites the actual publication date, 2008.

What's the best way to deal with these? Is this legal, given that I gave permission to download but not any Creative Commons license? Is there a `piracy@amazon.com` or other such email address one can request? And can I request that references to this paperback be redirected to my actual ebook or the hardcover I published on Lulu?

Is there any way to request that monies tendered to unauthorized printing be redirected to me?

Comment: Welcome to Writers SE. We are not experts on Google Books or Amazon. Have you tried contacting either or both of them? Have you contacted a copyright lawyer?

Comment: A couple of notes: (1) If your work was pirated, you should have legal recourse, although the specifics may be beyond our scope. A good start would be getting details on who's pirated your book. (2) In general, please avoid linking to your own books in your questions. The site's questions should be general enough to be helpful to others, and not relate only to your own book. It also gives your questions a promotional feel that we'd rather avoid.

Comment: (3) That being said, the "pirated" version of your book seems listed as a version of the same ebook you say is "good." That seems very odd, if they're not from the same publisher. Perhaps you used some ebook-promotion service that provided some incorrect data?

Comment: It may be listed as the same book; it came as a complete surprise to me and I never heard of Numa publications. The cover illustration also came as a complete surprise to me; I have never interacted with any publisher claiming or offering to make the mentioned paperbacks, and all of the trade dress, and publisher details, are novel to me.

Comment: I agree with @LaurenIpsum - This site isn't tech support for Amazon, and it's not a complaints department. This user has posted three questions, all complaining about Amazon.

Answer (score 2):

Under the "Product Details" heading, you have several links for updating book information and notifying Amazon of problems. That'd be a good way to try.

More directly, there's the [Contact Us](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/contact-us/) button on the help page. They should be able to direct you to the right place to alert them to the problem.